# Forward a sms to WhatsApp

Tags: iphone, shortcut, sms, whatsapp.app

Is there a way to forward an SMS from iPhone to WhatsApp?
For example, I have booked a movie ticket and received the booking id and details as SMS. I would like to forward that to my contacts on WhatsApp.

The only option I see now is to copy the SMS and go to WhatsApp contacts and paste it, which is tedious. Is there a better way to do this? Is there any `shortcut` actions available for the same?

Comment: Take a screenshot and use the sharing sheet?

Comment: That's an option, I'm looking for a better way to do that.

Comment: What would be „better“?